# missing libm.so.6 and libstdc++.so.6

Tags: dependencies, libraries, c, qt-creator, glibc

I have a program that I compiled through qt creator and appears to work fine on my computer but I'm trying to run it on a remote computer cluster and it spits out these error messages.

```
./programs/sampleapp: /lib64/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.29' not found (required by ./programs/sampleapp)
./programs/sampleapp: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.26' not found (required by ./programs/sampleapp)
./programs/sampleapp: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by ./programs/sampleapp)
```

I guess these dependencies are missing? I don't know where to find them. Googling for them doesn't lead me to anything that works and I've tried searching my own computer with no luck.

Comment: Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and official *flavors* of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.   *No on-topic system here provides the required library version so I'm betting you're not using an on-topic system*

Comment: AFAIK the message doesn't mean that the libraries are *missing*, it means they're too old - or, more specifically, that the program was built against newer versions of the libraries than are present on the target system.

Comment: Say your remote cluster has glibc /  libc6 version 2.27 : You will then have to build your application with an "libc6 - 2.27 OS" .... or on an even older OS. .... Example : Ubuntu 18.04 has  libc6 - 2.27 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just discovered why you need to rebuild applications for different flavours or even versions of Linux. Some might run on some variety of other distributions, but there is no guarantee.

In general, build your application on the machine (or at least on a machine with the same distribution) that you want to run it on. Or, better yet, build software *packages* (.deb for Ubuntu / Debian, .rpm for SUSE / Red Hat / Fedora / CentOS) to automate the process and to ensure that dependencies (like those shared libs) are handled automatically.

No, that's not an easy thing to do, but it's a necessary thing.

Comment: Okay my system is Ubuntu based but the target is CentOS 7. So I guess I will try to write a makefile and see if I can build it in there with gcc. and then I will maybe make a deb in the future if I need to run this in a bunch of places.

Comment: Since you mentioned Qt in the keywords of your question, better start with QMake or CMake. Manually written Makefiles are too painful for today's complexity, in particular when it comes wo what shared libs you need to link to your project and the exact parameters for that. Both QMake and CMake do that for you.

Comment: I finally got it to run after building it remotely. The funny thing is I've transferred previous versions of the program built with QT locally and ran it no problem on the same cluster. But I just take out a few sources files and suddenly its not portable anymore. Now I have to figure out why.